# Add new command to CMD without overriding existing

Tags: docker

I'm want to use existing docker image and add new command without overiding commands in cmd.

Dockerfile

```
FROM telegrammessenger/proxy

COPY mtproto_stats .

CMD [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/bash /run.sh", "/bin/bash ./mtproto_stats" ]
```

Here i try to execute my programm which i copied to container CMD [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/bash /run.sh", **"./mtproto_stats"** ]

This commands `"/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/bash /run.sh"` i got using `docker inspect` on running container

My programm should run with container and work all time, i'm trying use `"./mtproto_stats & disown"` but it not help

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @dpwrussell run `/run.sh` an then `./mtproto_stats`, but `./mtproto_stats` run only if i put it to entrypoint, but if put it to entrypoint `/run.sh` will not run

Comment: I don't think you understand what `entrypoint` and `command` actually do and also how command works. `command` is not a list of commands, it is a single command. If you want your container to do two things then you will need to make a run-script that you make the entrypoint. The run-script will then launch `run.sh` and then `mtproto_stats`, either one after the other, or if one/both are services, then by using one of many techniques to detach those processes.

Answer (score 1):

> This commands `"/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/bash /run.sh"` i got using docker inspect on running container

`"/bin/sh", "-c"` is the default [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint), `"/bin/bash /run.sh"` is the [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).

In your case, you should have, using the shell form of CMD:

```
FROM telegrammessenger/proxy

COPY mtproto_stats .
COPY wrapper.sh /wrapper.sh
CMD exec /wrapper.sh
```

With wrapper.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /path/to/mtproto_stats & disown
exec /run.sh
```

I place `run.sh` at the end, as it is supposed to be the main process, which keep the container alive.